# Кодил первый раз, не судите строго

Tags: arduino

Пытаюсь запустить следующий код:

```
int red = 5;
int yelow = 4;
int green = 3;
int blue = 2; 

void setup()
 { 
pinMode(red, OUTPUT); 
pinMode(yelow, OUTPUT);
pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
pinMode(blue, OUTPUT); 
}
void loop() {

  for(int value = 0; value <= 255;value ++) {
analogWrite (red, 0);
analogWrite (green, 255-value);
analogWrite (blue, value); 
delay(30); 
} 

  for(int value value = 0; value <= 255;value ++) { 
analogWrIte (red, 0); 
analogWrIte (green, 255-value);
analogWrfle (blue, value);
delay(30); 
}

  for(int value = 0; value <= 255;value ++) {
analogWrite (blue, 0);
analogWrite (red, 255-value);
analogWrfle (green, value); 
delay(30); 
}

  for(int value = 0; value <= 255;value ++) {
analogWrIte (green, 0);
analogWrIte (blue, 255-value);
analogWrfle (red, value); 
delay(30); 
}
  
}
```

Выбивает такие ошибки:

```
 In function 'void loop()':
24:17: error: expected ';' before 'value'
24:40: error: expected ')' before ';' token
24:41: error: 'value' was not declared in this scope
24:41: note: suggested alternative: 'blue'
34:1: error: 'analogWrfle' was not declared in this scope
34:1: note: suggested alternative: 'analogWrite'
39:1: error: 'analogWrIte' was not declared in this scope
39:1: note: suggested alternative: 'analogWrite'
41:1: error: 'analogWrfle' was not declared in this scope
41:1: note: suggested alternative: 'analogWrite'
 exit status 1
```

Comment: похоже здесь for(int value value = 0; - там явно один value лишний

Comment: `analogWrfle` - почитайте название внимательно

Comment: Мы-то не осудим, а вот компилятор не поймет, если терять точки с запятой и скобки, и путать буквы в названиях функций)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте исправить опечатки.

```
int red = 5;
int yelow = 4;
int green = 3;
int blue = 2; 

void setup()
{ 
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(yelow, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blue, OUTPUT); 
}

void loop() 
{
  for(int value = 0; value <= 255;value ++) {
    analogWrite (red, 0);
    analogWrite (green, 255-value);
    analogWrite (blue, value); 
    delay(30); 
  } 

  for(int value = 0; value <= 255;value ++) { 
    analogWrite (red, 0); 
    analogWrite (green, 255-value);
    analogWrite (blue, value);
    delay(30); 
  }

  for(int value = 0; value <= 255;value ++) {
    analogWrite (blue, 0);
    analogWrite (red, 255-value);
    analogWrite (green, value); 
    delay(30); 
  }

  for(int value = 0; value <= 255;value ++) {
    analogWrite (green, 0);
    analogWrite (blue, 255-value);
    analogWrite (red, value); 
    delay(30); 
  }

}
```